# Allow MySQL users access to select on all views, but not tables

Tags: mysql, view, permissions

How do I allow users to have select access to Views only, and not any of the underlying tables?

I know how to grand permissions one at a time using a

`grant select on database.viewName to 'User'`

but I am trying to make either a user or a profile that have access to all views without running the grants 1 by 1 whenever a new view is created.

In Sequel Pro, under Users>Global Privileges and Schema Privileges I added "Show View" but this is not working.

Comment: Maybe I worded this poorly. I understand running 

`grant select on database.viewName to 'User'`

will grant access to one view.  I would like a user profile set up where the users automatically have access to pull the content from ALL views, but not the underlying tables.  When new Views are created, the users will have access without having to run another batch of grant scripts.  With new tables, they will still not have access.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was verified using MySQL 8.0.23.

1. Make sure that your views are set to run using the credentials of the `DEFINER`, that way the invoking user doesn't require any `TABLE` privileges; not doing this will result in an error. For more details on the `{DEFINER|INVOKER}` parameter [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).
2. Create your user, allocating no privileges at all.
3. As `root` or another user with sufficient privileges, execute the following command:

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON <database>.<view_name> TO '<user>'@'<host>';
   ```

So if my database were `cars` and the view were called `service_history`, and I had a user `john.doe` that needed to access this from any host, I would execute the following:

```
GRANT SELECT ON cars.service_history TO 'john.doe'@'%';
```

Note how `'%'` was used to indicate any host is acceptable, you can replace this with an IP address, maybe a hostname (but I have not tested that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.

Mysql `GRANT` commands take the form `GRANT permission ON object_type`

> The object_type clause, if present, should be specified as TABLE, FUNCTION, or PROCEDURE when the following object is a table, a stored function, or a stored procedure.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

I don't believe there's any facility for granting permissions solely on a view.

Keep in mind that, in mysql, a view is just a query which is executed whenever you SELECT from it. It has no data storage or indexes of its own. As such, I expect you have to have access to the underlying tables in order for the view to be usable.

Comment: This answer is incorrect! As the linked documentation says: `Table-level privileges apply to base tables and views. ` The right solution is to create the view to run in the name of the definer, who must have select access to the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

I will show it, might take a few edits to do it. Because I have to attach console output at the bottom.

### Schema

```
create table users
(   userId int auto_increment primary key,
    userName varchar(100) not null
    -- etc
);
insert users(userName) values ('Joe'),('Gertrude');

-- drop table secretdata;
create table SecretData
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    theKey varchar(100) not null,
    theValue varchar(1000) not null,
    key(userId),
    CONSTRAINT fk_sd_users FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId)
);
insert secretdata(userId,theKey,theValue) values 
(1,'FB Password','8*&Fjj_anchovieS'),
(1,'Proper response','I love the meal, just like I like it'),
(2,'thing7','goat');
```

### The view

```
CREATE VIEW userSecrets AS 
    select u.userId,u.userName,s.theKey,s.theValue
    from users u
    join SecretData s
    on s.userId=u.userId;
```

`select * from userSecrets where userId=2;` -- works here at the moment

Note my db name is `so_gibberish`.

**The following is what you are asking about for grant rights to view:**

```
GRANT SELECT ON so_gibberish.userSecrets TO 'john'@'host';
```

↑ ↑ **users so provisioned can then rifle off queries against the view.** ↑ ↑

however,

```
CREATE USER 'plebian2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT SELECT ON so_gibberish.userSecrets TO 'plebian2'@'localhost';
```

That user does have rights to use the view, but **does not** have access to the underlying tables directly.

Console output:

```
OS Prompt>mysql -u plebian2 -p
Enter password: ******

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 938
Server version: 5.6.24-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| so_gibberish       |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use so_gibberish;
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+------------------------+
| Tables_in_so_gibberish |
+------------------------+
| usersecrets            |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'plebian2'@'localhost' for table 'users'

mysql> select * from usersecrets;
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| userId | userName | theKey          | theValue                             |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
|      1 | Joe      | FB Password     | 8*&Fjj_anchovieS                     |
|      1 | Joe      | Proper response | I love the meal, just like I like it |
|      2 | Gertrude | thing7          | goat                                 |
+--------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lastly, I hope, see Manual Page entitled [Access Control for Stored Programs and Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-security.html) to see how the **Definer** permissions factor into the end-state effective rights. In particular, when the definer has *less* privileges than the user account using the view (a rather weird condition, but there it is).

### Roles

In response to your comment under the Answer.

I was basically dissatisfied with the lack of roles embedded in mysql coming from the Microsoft world where they existed. Meaning, there are made-up roles, users are attached to roles, and grants are performed at the role level (in the MSFT world). There, in MSSQL, at the bottom of each create whatever block (stored proc etc), would be my block that did grants at the role level.

So coming into mysql, I had to create that role to user mapping. Good news, I only had to do it once. And the end of the chunk (if exist drop / create) that I run, it makes calls that directly manipulate the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.user_privileges` and the like. But at a very high level, just like with MSFT, with the end result being what I wanted. That is, permissions granted.

That is a whole can of worms. But without it, good luck.

The commands like `grant` and some other commands can be performed on your own under the hood. There is little sacred about them. Yet they are there to protect novice programmers. And those that foresake those Warning Signs saying be careful are often left thinking,

> "How do I get my data back. I know it's in there somewhere. Maybe I
>   shouldn't have done that under the hood thing I just did"

But definitely something to tinker with, especially in a throwaway db (one you don't care about). Even better, do it on a mysql instance you don't care about. Because we are talking about system wide implications at a higher level than at the db level.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this still requires running the grant for each user on each view whenever one is added.  This is what I have been using and is not sufficient for a long term solution.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using user() as the filter on the tables and setting SQL SECURITY DEFINER, using separate schemas for views and source tables.

Example code

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `xxxxxx`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `XX`.`assets` AS
    SELECT 
        `a`.`ID` AS `ID`,
        `a`.`serial_no` AS `serial_no`,
        `a`.`sys_id` AS `sys_id`,
        `a`.`status` AS `status`,
        `a`.`unit_name` AS `unit_name`,
        `a`.`ip` AS `ip`,
        `a`.`tzOffset` AS `tzOffset`
    FROM
        ((`YY`.`Cust_Link_Table` `l`
        JOIN `YY`.`systems` `s` ON ((`l`.`cust_id` = `s`.`cust_id`)))
        JOIN `YY`.`assets` `a` ON ((`s`.`sys_id` = `a`.`sys_id`)))
    WHERE
        (`l`.`db_user` = CONVERT( LEFT(USER(), (LOCATE('@', USER()) - 1)) USING UTF8MB4))
```